# Creating a dictionary of the words in text

Tags: python, dictionary, text, enumerate

I want to create a dictionary of all unique words in the text. The key is the word and the value is the word's frequency

```
dtt = ['you want home at our peace', 'we went our home', 'our home is nice', 'we want peace at home']
word_listT = str(' '.join(dtt)).split()
wordsT = {v:k for (k, v) in enumerate(word_listT)}
print wordsT
```

I expect something like this:

```
{'we': 2, 'is': 1, 'peace': 2, 'at': 2, 'want': 2, 'our': 3, 'home': 4, 'you': 1, 'went': 1, 'nice': 1}
```

However, I receive this:

```
{'we': 14, 'is': 12, 'peace': 16, 'at': 17, 'want': 15, 'our': 10, 'home': 18, 'you': 0, 'went': 7, 'nice': 13}
```

Apparently, I am misusing the functionality or doing something wrong.

Please, help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with what you are doing is you are storing the array index of where the word is instead of a count of those words.

To achieve this you can just use `collections.Counter`

```
from collections import Counter

dtt = ['you want home at our peace', 'we went our home', 'our home is nice', 'we want peace at home']
counted_words = Counter(' '.join(dtt).split())
# if you want to see what the counted words are you can print it
print counted_words

>>> Counter({'home': 4, 'our': 3, 'we': 2, 'peace': 2, 'at': 2, 'want': 2, 'is': 1, 'you': 1, 'went': 1, 'nice': 1})
```

**SOME CLEANUP:** as mentioned in the comments

`str()` is unnecessary for your `' '.join(dtt).split()`

You can also remove the list assignment and do your counter on the same line

```
Counter(' '.join(dtt).split())
```

A little more detail about your list indices; first you have to understand what your code is doing.

```
dtt = [
    'you want home at our peace', 
    'we went our home', 
    'our home is nice', 
    'we want peace at home'
]
```

Notice you have 19 words here; `print len(word_listT)` returns 19. Now on the next line `word_listT = str(' '.join(dtt)).split()` you are making a list of all of the words, which looks like this

```
word_listT = [
    'you', 
    'want', 
    'home', 
    'at', 
    'our', 
    'peace', 
    'we', 
    'went', 
    'our', 
    'home', 
    'our', 
    'home', 
    'is', 
    'nice', 
    'we', 
    'want', 
    'peace', 
    'at', 
    'home'
]
```

Count them again: 19 words. The very last word is 'home'. And list indices start at 0 so 0 to 18 = 19 elements. `yourlist[18]` is 'home'. This has nothing to do with the string location or anything, just the index of your new array. :)

Comment: @Toly of course! glad I could help! You should look around inside collections, there are a lot of useful tools in there.. `Counter` is one, I use `defaultdict` all the time too. If you have any more questions feel free to ask and I'll try and help if I can :)

Comment: @JohnRuddell join() returns a string, why do you want to cast it to string again? Counter(' '.join(dtt).split()) will do

Comment: @helloV sorry I had just copied what the OP did there without really reading it. the Counter part was what I was adding. but yes str() is completely unnecessary there

Comment: @JohnRuddell - a question. I understand that the numbers represent indexes (in my code). But why the index is at 18 while there are fewer than 18 words in dictionary? Does it take indexes from the original string? If yes, how can I make sure that indexes are from the dictionary and not from the original string?

Comment: @Toly its easier to explain with code so look at the edit I did. I hope that helps. Let me know if you still don't understand or have another question :)

Comment: @JohnRuddell - John thank you for your explanation! My question is: how can I get the index of the word in a dictionary (and have it as a value maybe) instead of the index from the original string?

Comment: @Toly there is no index for a dictionary. there is a key and a value. the key is `'home'` the value is the count in our case here. so like from my answer `counted_words['home']` would give you `4`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

dtt = ['you want home at our peace', 'we went our home', 'our home is nice', 'we want peace at home']
word_list = str(' '.join(dtt)).split()
d = defaultdict(int)
for word in word_list:
    d[word] += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

`enumerate` returns a list of words with their indices, not with their frequency. That is, when you create the wordsT dictionary, each `v` is actually the index in word_listT of the last instance of `k`. To do what you want, using a for-loop is probably the most straightforward.

```
wordsT = {}
for word in word_listT:
    try:
        wordsT[word]+=1
    except KeyError:
        wordsT[word] = 1
```